# Redux error state or error is showing in another page even it was cleared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My code:

## LOGIN.JSX

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("empty useEffect triggered");
        setErrors({});
        dispatch(resetState());
    }, []);

    const { handleChange, handleSubmit, formData, errors, setErrors } = useForm(
        formInput,
        doSubmit,
        schema
    );

    function doSubmit() {
        dispatch(login(formData));
    }
    const isSubmitting = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isSubmitting);
    const serverSideErrors = useSelector((state) => state.auth.errors);
    const authUser = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
    const redirectTo = useSelector((state) => state.auth.redirectTo);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("serverSideErrors useEffect triggered");
        //TODO:: preven server error to override on error on mount register => login
        if (Object.keys(serverSideErrors).length > 0) {
            setErrors(serverSideErrors);
        }
        if (!_.isEmpty(authUser)) {
            console.log("authUser", authUser);
            history.push(redirectTo);
        }
    }, [serverSideErrors, authUser]);
```

and is the small portion of render (email field only)

```
<div className="form-group mb-3">
    <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
    <input
        className={`form-control ${
            errors["name"]
                ? "is-invalid"
                : ""
        }`}
        type="text"
        id="name"
        name="name"
        required=""
        placeholder="Enter your name"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={formData.name}
    />
    <span
        className={
            errors["name"]
                ? "invalid-feedback d-inline-block"
                : "d-none"
        }
    >
        {errors["name"]}
    </span>
</div>
```

## Register.jsx

```
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrors({});
        dispatch(resetState());
    }, []);

    const { handleChange, handleSubmit, formData, errors, setErrors } = useForm(
        formInput,
        doSubmit,
        schema
    );

    function doSubmit() {
        // loadingBtn.start();
        dispatch(register(formData));
    }

    const serverSideErrors = useSelector((state) => state.auth.errors);
    const isSubmitting = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isSubmitting);
    const registered = useSelector((state) => state.auth.registered);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (Object.keys(serverSideErrors).length > 0) {
            setErrors(serverSideErrors);
        }
        if (registered) {
            // loadingBtn.stop();
            toastify.success(
                "Successfully Created. Confirmation email has been sent to the email."
            );
            history.push("/login");
        }
    }, [serverSideErrors, registered]);
```

Here, I am  using same error state for both login and register (for auth module). and as you can see on I have tried to reset the state on each component mount via useEffect. on useEffect I have dispatched `resetState` and resetState looks like:

```
export const resetState = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authActions.RESET());
};

...
...
...


const initialState = {
    isSubmitting: false,
    loading: false,

    redirectTo: null,

    user: {},
    registered: false,
    registerErrors: {},
    errors: {},
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        SET_IS_SUBMITTING: (state, action) => {
            state.isSubmitting = action.payload.isSubmitting;
        },
        REGISTER_SUCCESS: (state, action) => {
            console.log("register payload", action.payload);
            // state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.isSubmitting = false;
            state.registered = true;
        },
        REGISTER_FAIL: (state, action) => {
            state.errors = action.payload.errors;
            state.isSubmitting = false;
        },

        LOGIN_SUCCESS: (state, action) => {
            state.isSubmitting = false;
            state.user = action.payload.user;
            state.redirectTo = action.payload.redirectTo;
        },
        LOGIN_FAIL: (state, action) => {
            state.errors = action.payload.errors;
            state.isSubmitting = false;
        },

        VERIFY_SUCCESS: (state, action) => {
            console.log("action.payload >>", action.payload);
            state.redirectTo = action.payload.redirectTo;
        },
        VERIFY_FAIL: (state, action) => {
            state.errors = action.payload.errors;
        },

        RESET: (state, action) => {
            return initialState;
        },
    },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice;
```

WHAT I AM DOING??

- first I attempt to register using already used email and I received the error dispatched `REGISTER_FAIL`  and this one update the redux state errors.
- now I click on login link to go to login page, but there I am seeing this errors on email field.

Picture of Redux State
[image: redux state]

And, here is the console log image
[image: console.log]

I could not figured it out why it is acting weird. I don't want the erros from register page to be shown on login page too.

## update

final redux state image, it is same as above shown but its from state tab instead of diff
[image]

My Assumption: IT looks like the render is running first than the useEffect, that's why it is rendering errors and later updating the state. How could I fix it?

Comment: Try changing your reset action to  RESET: (state, action) => {
             state = initialState;
        },

Comment: I encountered the same issue when i was using the return state , but somehow using the assignment instead fixed the issue

Comment: same issue, infact i had used it earlier, and with that approach it was not even resetting the state. I could clearly see the errors state with actual error with this approach.

Comment: Does it make errors disappear if you only selectively reset the errors? like  state.errors={}

Comment: from the approached I mentioned in qiestion the errors state is already updated to {} but still it is showing errors, that's what the issue, you can check the latest picture, there is no errors on redux state, yet it is showing errors.

Comment: I can see that you are using setErrors in the useffect but its not going to reset as you've put it in the condition  if (Object.keys(serverSideErrors).length > 0). So when the state resets to {} it wont go into that condition will never call setErrors to update the state. What is the use of this condition?

Comment: My Assumption: IT looks like the render is running first than the useEffect, that's why it is rendering errors and later updating the state. How could I fix it?

Comment: HI @AayushDahal, currently I'm facing same issue , do you have the solution to solve it? Thank You.

Comment: I had changed the order, first reset errors and load the page.